# How do I allow users to sort posts?

Tags: sort

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I sort multiples pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73367/how-do-i-sort-multiples-pages)

I want to allow users to sort a long list of posts (that are displayed on multiple pages) by custom fields.

Here is my form...

```
<form method="post" id="order">
  <select name="sort" onchange='this.form.submit()'>
    <option value="">Sort by</option>  
    <option value="zip">Sort by Zip Code</option>
    <option value="type">Sort by Property Type</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

I was told that I need to use sessions. However, I don't know how to code this. Could anyone give me an example based on the form above?

Comment: Never submit a form `onchange`. It will be very hard for keyboard users to reach the third item.

Comment: we need a little bit more information... its not an issuse to sort posts using select but what are those parameters?... custom fields? meta boxes? if you wanted to can you create a loop that would show post by zip code by default? what does that even mean? does that mean that 15758 would be before 25841 ?

Comment: As my first sentence indicated, the posts will be sorted by "custom fields" (i.e., zip code, property type, property name, etc.) For zip code, it simply means that the posts will be sorted in numeric order. So, yes, zip code 15758 would be before 25841. Thanks so much.

Comment: All the code is in the answer to you other question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73367/how-do-i-sort-multiples-pages

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query to the URL in WordPress, and then just link to that query, see – http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg